I can't find a piece of data in IDA
I have this book I have to read for school and there's this exercise to create a program in Visual Studio in C language that prints "Hello!" and insert it into IDA. Then you need to find where the String "Hello!" that was defined in the program was saved, which I believe I found. Then it says:

Inside our main, we will focus on two lines. The first, aHello offset push. This line pushes into the stack the memory address of the Hello string. If we click on aHello we will be directed to the address of the string in memory", however, I cannot find this line nor the keyword "aHello" anywhere in the IDA.

After that, there's an example photo  and the following text:

It can be seen that the string is defined at the address 416B94 and after it is defined the character 0Ah (as remembered from the assembly studies,
line drop) followed by the character 0 (as you remember, indicates the end of the string for printing functions).

I tried to go to that line but I couldn't find it. I was wondering if I could get some on understanding the IDA.
The code I used in the program is
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello!");
    return 0;
}

I'm sorry if I phrased anything wrong. The book is not in English an I'm new to IDA and C language.


The instruction should be push offset aHello and not aHello offset push. Maybe it's written differently in IDA or generated differently by your compiler - follow the XREF from the aHello line to see where it's used.

You seem to be describing here what your book says you should be seeing, but what do you actually see?

@interjay I also can't find that line as well. I generally can't find the word aHello in any data segment whatsoever.

You showed it in the screenshot. Or did you post a screenshot from the book for some reason?

@500-Internal Server Error is there a way for me to somehow upload the entire IDA file? I don't know which part I should put a picture of.

The picture is from the book @interjay

Well, I don't have IDA installed ATM, and it's been a while since I used it, but do you see anything "main" on your IDA screen? (you should, I think, assuming your program was built with debug information)

@500-InternalServerError The question is about a string literal, which is probably in a different segment from the main() function.

@500-Internal Server Error as far as I saw, there's one. Although I don't see anything there.  I added it to the body question.

Ah, it's right there in the middle of your screen shot: 1400118ac: lea rcx, _Format ; "Hello!". This loads the address of the "Hello!" string (named Format) into ecx. The book was probably based on a different version of the compiler from what you're using, maybe a 32-bit one - what you have here is 64-bit code.

@500-Internal Server Error I guess that's where it is saved. Yet, I still cannot find the push offset aHello line. Is it still needed or do I now don't need it?

Looks like your book is describing a 32-bit example where it pushes a pointer to your format string (automatically named aHello) onto the stack before calling printf.
Your binary is 64-bit with a different calling convention where the rcx register is used to hold the pointer to your format string (automatically named _Format) instead of the stack (so no push instruction needed).
If you go to where _Format is defined (perhaps use the XREF feature to find it), you will find the bytes that make up your string.
(Looks like your version of IDA is using the function argument's name to generate a name, while the book's version used the contents of the string to generate the name.)

I clicked the Hello on the _Format line and it took me to the line _Format         db 'Hello!',0           ; DATA XREF: main+1C↑o isn't supposed to take me to the data SEG? Like  when you use Assembly and debug it in the DOSBox where it's all in Hexadecimal?
And does it replace the push offset aHello line?

@yarden I would assume that is probably in a read-only data segment, although I can't verify from what you pasted. This calling convention uses a register instead of the stack, so there won't be a push instruction, just a register assignment.

It did take you to rdata segment (because C string literals are immutable, the compiler places them into read-only data). To the left of that copy-paste there would be something like .rdata:.... just like in that example you gave in the question.
